# GAM-GEE in R using Yags package

Tags: r, statistics, gam

I am trying to use a GAM_GEE in R using Yags package, I have been following Pirotta's code which can be found here (http://www.int-res.com/articles/suppl/m436p257_supp/m436p257_supp1-code.r).

I am trying to do a step wise selection of the models but am having limited success as when removing variables, i get the following error code.

```
Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

This is my full model:

```
 fit2<-yags(Species ~ bs(Lat,knots=mean(Lat))+bs(Lon,knots=mean(Lon))+bs(Depth,knots=mean(Depth))
       +bs(Slope,knots=mean(Slope))+Aspect+SST+bs(Distance,knots=mean(Distance))+Side,
       family=binomial,corstruct="independence", id=Tow)
```

I can successfully remove Depth,but not any other variables in the model without the error code.

I have tried converting all variables to factors, characters and integers, but with no success.

This is my first time using this analysis